# Logitech mouse thumb button not showing in xev

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, logitech

I recently got the Logitech M720. Pressing the thumb button in xev gives the following:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x270, subw 0x0, time 1922861, (169,43), root:(248,150),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x270, subw 0x0, time 1922894, (169,43), root:(248,150),
    state 0x4, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

LeaveNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x270, subw 0x0, time 1922894, (169,43), root:(248,150),
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 12

EnterNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x270, subw 0x0, time 1922920, (169,43), root:(248,150),
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 12

KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  112 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Trying to bind it in gnome keyboard shortcuts does not work either. There is no button entry in xev.

Using `xev | grep keycode`:

```
state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
state 0x4, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
```

In windows this button causes an alt tab, is it trying to do the same here?

Comment: It defaults to Ctrl+Alt+Tab for me on Ubuntu 16.04.  Haven't found a way to remap it yet though.

Comment: Why not to change the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+Tab to the one you want?

Comment: I get the same thing.  The thumb-dwown button which is usually mouse button 10 sends a:

request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    state 0x14, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    state 0x1c, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
And then it hangs xev

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before. I accidentally solved it after reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 for other reasons.

In my case, it was `imwheel` restricting the use of thumb buttons. In my `.imwheelrc`, I have

```
".*"
None,       Up,     Up,     5
None,       Down,   Down,   5
```

It was meant to increase scroll speed, but also blocks thumb buttons. (You do **not** have to use the same setting as mine in imwheelrc). To make them available again, in **terminal**,first do: `killall imwheel`  then do `imwheel -b "4 5"`.
It works by limiting the button grab to the specified buttons.

Note: I do **NOT** have `xautomation` installed. I would try uninstall xautomation if above steps doesn't work.